# VBS Runtime error code 800A01B6

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

I am a newbie to VBS scripting. I am getting above error on line 54, character 5 in script below.  This error says "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'MimeMapArray'".

And line it is referring to is:
    MimeMapArray(i) = CreateObject("MimeMap")

Can u tell me what I am doing wrong?  Here is the script in its entirety.  Note, I am trying to run this on an XP OS by double-clicking this VBS file.

```
' This script adds the necessary Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types 
' to an IIS Server.
' To use this script, just double-click or execute it from a command line.
' Running this script multiple times results in multiple entries in the IIS MimeMap.
' Set the MIME types to be added
Dim MimeMapObj
Dim MimeMapArray
Dim WshShell
Dim oExec
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2

Dim MimeTypesToAddArray
MimeTypesToAddArray = Array(".manifest", "application/manifest", ".xaml", _
    "application/xaml+xml", ".application", "application/x-ms-application", _
    ".deploy", "application/octet-stream", ".xbap", "application/x-ms-xbap", _
    ".xps", "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument")

' Get the mimemap object 
Set MimeMapObj = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/MimeMap")

' Call AddMimeType for every pair of extension/MIME type
For counter = 0 to UBound(MimeTypesToAddArray) Step 2
    AddMimeType MimeTypesToAddArray(counter), MimeTypesToAddArray(counter+1)
Next

' Create a Shell object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Stop and Start the IIS Service
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net stop w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net start w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = Nothing

' Report status to user
WScript.Echo "Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types have been registered."

' AddMimeType Sub
Sub AddMimeType(ByVal Ext, ByVal MType)

    ' Get the mappings from the MimeMap property. 
    MimeMapArray = MimeMapObj.GetEx("MimeMap")

    ' Add a new mapping. 
    i = UBound(MimeMapArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve MimeMapArray(i)
    MimeMapArray(i) = CreateObject("MimeMap")
    MimeMapArray(i).Extension = Ext
    MimeMapArray(i).MimeType = MType
    MimeMapObj.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE, "MimeMap", MimeMapArray
    MimeMapObj.SetInfo()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I can suggest is use cscript to execute.  You can get more information that won't go away like with a message box.

1. Open a command prompt (go to start,
   run, type CMD).
2. Go to the location where your script
   is and type the following:

> cscript scriptname.vbs

...where scriptname.vbs is the name of your script.

Second, you appear to be missing the "set" in front of your createobject line.  Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp) for reference.

That line should look like:

```
set MimeMapArray(i) = CreateObject("MimeMap")
```